# How to fix "bone heat weighting failed to find solution for one or more bones" I tried everything!

Tags: rigging, bones

I have tried every solution i could find here and nothing seems to be working. I'm a beginner I only know the basics. Can someone help me with it?

Here is the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Y7lKjOV4p28ZmlqfE-aOFoxmD8g8PuU

If someone can fix it i would be so grateful.

Edit: i tried Remove Doubles, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i find the error come from your hairmesh
this may solve the problem

Comment: i can't make the merge distance 0.0005, when i put it- it was changed it back to 0.0001